# Django 4 Model Forms - Adding Widgets Code Syntax

Tags: django-forms

I am new to Django and ModelForms and I am having issues adding widgets. My problems are that: A - I am struggling to find much information on the subject of ModelForms and B - The information I have found all seems to differ. Below is a snippet of my current code. This is giving me an error "forms is not defined". I have also tried the options below in various combinations, all of which throw up errors:

- "from django import forms"
- class EggCollectionForm(forms.ModelForm)
- Removing "forms." from before "IntegerField"

Any assistance and guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, widgets
from .models import EggCollection, FeedingTime, CoopCleaning


class EggCollectionForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = EggCollection
        fields = ('date',
                  'qty_egg_trays')

        widgets = {
            'qty_egg_trays': forms.IntegerField(attrs={'class':
                                                       'egg-collection-qty-input \
                                                       saleable-eggs-input \
                                                       average-weight-input',
                                                       'id': 'qty-egg-trays',
                                                       'name': 'qty_egg_trays',
                                                       'placeholder': 'Qty Laid Trays',
                                                       'value': ''})}
```

Answer (score 0):

IntegerField is for Models, NumberInput is for forms... at least I think. Just taking a crack at it.

[image]

```
class EggCollectionForm(ModelForm):

  class Meta:
    model = EggCollection
    fields = ('date',
              'qty_egg_trays')
    widgets = {
        'qty_egg_trays': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':
                                                   'egg-collection-qty-input \
                                                   saleable-eggs-input \
                                                   average-weight-input',
                                                   'id': 'qty-egg-trays',
                                                   'name': 'qty_egg_trays',
                                                   'placeholder': 'Qty Laid Trays',
                                                   'value': ''})}
```